# Find word in textbox and get line number with this word C#

Tags: string, text, textbox, text-files, line

I have a problem, I have a text in texbox1 and I would like to search for a word there, and if I find it, I would like to get the line number from texbox1 where the found word is... is there such a possibility because I have already dug the whole internet and I can not find a solution :(

I try this:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iL = 0;
    
    foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
    {
        iL += 1;
        if (line == "someword")
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox1.Lines[iL].Remove(0, 15);
        }
    }

}
```

please help me because I am losing my mind :/

Comment: Hello is somebody who can help in this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just do it by my self ;) so thx for help...
And for others who want anwser..

```
 string line = textBox1.Lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("test"));
            if (line != null)

            {
                textBox2.AppendText(line+Environment.NewLine); //all line with string test
                textBox2.AppendText(line.Remove(0, 47) + Environment.NewLine);//only string test without 47 char from begining
            }
```